# C functions called in main() not returning value

Tags: c, function, file, program-entry-point

I am working on a C program with multiple functions that reads in text files and returns the count of lines, blank lines, comments, etc. However, when I call multiple functions in main() only the first function called returns its value. The other functions return - 0. Why? What is the correct way to call the functions?

[Terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4mEz.png)

Example code:

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <string.h>
#include  <stdlib.h>

int non_blank_lines(FILE *input);
int all_lines(FILE *input);

main (int argc , char **argv)
{
    char file_name[40];
    
    //prompting a user to enter a file name
    printf("Please enter a file name: ");
    scanf("%s", file_name);
    
    //opening and reading the file
    FILE *input = fopen(file_name, "r");
     
    //check if the entered file exists
    if (input == NULL) 
    { 
        printf("File %s does not exist!", file_name); 
        return 0; 
    } 

    //calling the functions and printing the output
    printf("The file %s has %d filled lines.\n", file_name, non_blank_lines(input));
    printf("The file %s has in total %d lines.\n", file_name, all_lines(input));
    
    
    fclose(input);
    return 0;
}

int non_blank_lines(FILE *input)
{
    int count = 0;
    char line[100];

    while(fgets(line, 100, input) != NULL)
    {
        if(strcmp(line, "\0") != 0 && strcmp(line, "\t") != 0 && strcmp(line, "\n") != 0)
            
            count = count + 1;
    }

    return count;
}

int all_lines(FILE *input)
{
    //searching for a new line character to count number of lines in a file
    int line_count = 0;
    char character;

    while((character = getc(input)) !=EOF)
    {
        if (character == '\n')
        line_count = line_count + 1;  
    }
        
    return line_count;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to `rewind()` the file pointer.

Comment: The 1st function *consumes* all the lines in the file... the 2nd function has nothing to read.

Comment: Aside `char character` should be `int character` because that is what is returned by `getc()` (to enable the caller to distinguish data `0xFF` and EOF `-1`).

Comment: You should count simultaneously both the total number of lines and blank lines within a single function. Otherwise one of the function will consume all of the stream and nothing will be left to the other function to read.

Comment: Do you realize you don't need to read the file *twice* for counting blank and non-blank lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fgets() reads the entire line, so there is nothing left for getc() to read.